# Explorer.exe - System Warning 'Unknown Hard Error'

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

So, probably my fault, I ran multiple different tools (one by one) yesterday to scan computer from malware and viruses. I used these tools:

```
- Combofix
- Autoruns
- TDSSKiller
- RogueKiller
- HijackThis
- RKill
- Malwarebytes
- Spybot
- Avast
```

So, it did clean everything, there wasn't much though. Anyway, since then, each time restarting PC and loading up Windows the error message box pops up `Explorer.exe - System Warning 'Unknown Hard Error'`

And I cannot trace back what is causing it. Even Viewer is empty.
I did follow various guides online, like editing regedit and deleting the Load key. I don't even have it.
Did all the chkdsk /r /f and sfc /scannow.
Tried running Safe Mode clean boot, etc.

I think that it was either Autoruns or HijackThis and I selected/deselected something wrong.

I did the system restore.

No, I am not willing to reinstall Windows or format hard drive just for that. I'm tired of reading various Windows support websites and forums about how all these experts 'advice' to format and reinstall Windows for every issue. I mean come on...

Thanks and cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

That error sounds to me like an internal error within `explorer.exe` or one if its dependencies, possibly a corrupt file.

You say that reformatting is not an option, can you still boot from a Windows Install disk? From here you will be able to launch a repair that will scan for, and replace any corrupt files it might find.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm answering my own question, but I did manage to fix it by running Tweaking.com - Windows Repair All in one. It looks like it does all the work when you run it in Safe mode and wait for an hour, it does it's magic.

Still can't explain what was the cause.